# Error al importar SyncStorage

Tags: react-native, aplicación-web, expo, paquetes-npm, async-storage

Cuando ejecuto en consola  npx expo start, todo va bien. Pulso w para verlo en la web y sigue bien pero no se carga la web. Es cuando actualizo la url   en consola aparece este error en  /node_modules/sync-storage/src/ index.js
you may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

import handleError from './helpers/handleError';

en línea 5:   type KeyType = string;

Comment: Podes dar algún detalle mas? es imposible saber lo que esta mal con la poca información que das

Comment: creo que tiene que ver con la instalación de react-native

Comment: a ver si se puede ver esta imagen del error en consola   http://adimex.es/errorSyncStorage.png

Comment: Asegúrate de que el modulo 'sync-storage' sea compatible con Expo, no todas las herramientas de React-Native son compatibles con Expo